# Playwright .NET - Element Visible but click fails

Tags: .net, playwright

I'm trying to open a URL and read the title of the page. When the page opens, it throws a few pop ups which need to be closed before reading the title text.

```
        var locator = page.Locator(selector);
        await locator.ClickAsync();
```

I get this error :

```
Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "button.over-aged"
  selector resolved to visible <button type="button" class="over-aged" data-role="actio…>…</button>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
============================================================
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.<InnerSendMessageToServerAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 186
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Connection.<WrapApiCallAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Connection.cs:line 485
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at PuppeteerExample.Program.<closePopUp>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\harsh\source\repos\puptest\puptest\Program.cs:line 42
```

From the above error I understand that the selector is not the problem, but the click fails for some odd reason. I found a bug report on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5765) that says this error was faced in version 1.9.1/1.9.2 but works fine in 1.8.1
I am currently using Playwright 1.22.0

Any help to would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `force: true` to disable actionability cecks

```
page.ClickAsync("selector", force: true);
```